# Combobox does not reflect the initial object value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a List of objects, and a few fields inside a Grid. When an object in the List(`lvInvoices`) is selected, I update the dataBinding of the Grid (`lyDetailForm`):

```
private void lvInvoices_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  int index = lvInvoices.SelectedIndex;
  if (index != -1)
  {
    Invoice selectedInvoice = this.ListItems.ElementAt(index);
    lyDetailForm.DataContext = selectedInvoice;
    ((PdfViewer)this.pdfControlHost.Child).File = selectedInvoice.SourceFile.FullName;
  }
}
```

In `lyDetailForms`, I have several controls. When I set the DataContext of the grid, the text controls are updated correctly. Yet the combobox appears white until I set it once; after that it is updated correctly when I change the selected item.

```
<Grid Name="lyDetailForm" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
  <TextBox Name="tbNif"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Margin="5" IsEnabled="{Binding SpId, Converter={x:Static local:SpSentToBooleanConverter.Instance}, ConverterParameter=NEGATE, FallbackValue=False}" Text="{Binding Nif,ValidatesOnExceptions=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Validation.Error="OnEditBoxError"/>
  <ComboBox Name="cbType" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" IsEnabled="{Binding SpId, Converter={x:Static local:SpSentToBooleanConverter.Instance}, ConverterParameter=NEGATE, FallbackValue=False}" Text="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay} ItemsSource="{Binding Types}"/>
</Grid>
```

By the way, `Types` is a static property from the same `invoice` object which returns an array of strings `String[]`. Combobox items are strings.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not seeing the ComboBx binding its SelectedItem anywhere.

Comment: You are right, I was binding Text instead. Yet it has worked until I started setting default values to the object. If you put this as an answer I'll grant it to you.

Comment: No, wait for someone to describe the Test/Selected semantics better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using the `cbType` ComboBox as TextBox and this is wrong, remove the `Text="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay}` binding and set the binding of the ComboBox selected item to something like this `SelectedItem={Binding SelectedType}` where `SelectedType` represent the currently selected Type.